# plotly subploted the shared xaxis of date string undesirably

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

*plotly 4.1.1*

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x = ["2019-09-01", "2019-09-02", "2019-09-04"]
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=x, y=[1, 2, 3], name="1st"), row=1, col=1) 
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=x, y=[3, 2, 1], name="2nd"), row=2, col=1) 
fig.update_layout(xaxis={'type': 'category'})
fig.show()
```

Below, the *1st* subplot showed correctly on *xaxis* of type *category*, but the *2nd* stuck to *xasis* of type *date* undesirably.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*update_xaxes* in place of *update_layout(xaxis)* solved the problem.

```py
fig.update_xaxes(type='category', row=1, col=1)
fig.update_xaxes(type='category', row=2, col=1)
```